# Having problems with bash array $PIPESTATUS

Tags: bash, awk, osx, pipe, io-redirection

I'm working on a script (that will run on OSX, and probably nothing else), that basically just parses the `/var/log/accountpolicy.log*` logs for authentication times/counts. The initial command is a `zgrep` executed via `sudo`, which is piped to `awk`, executing an awk script. After the command is ran, I use `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` to determine if anything failed, and if so, which part.

Here's the awk script in its current state:

```awk
#! /usr/local/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  return_code = 0
  if ( length( username ) == 0 ){
    return_code = 2
    exit return_code
  }

  rows = 0
}
{ 
  if ( $8 != sprintf("\"%s\",", username ) ) next

  rows = rows+1
  print $0
} 
END {
  if ( return_code > 0 ) exit return_code
  if ( rows == 0 ) exit 3
}
```

The awk script has some custom value validation and exit codes. The return codes 1, 2 and 3 mean:

1. Awk failed (for some reason related to awk)
2. No username was specified for awk to parse for
3. The username was specified, but no values were found

#### Test #1 (working properly)

An example execution (hiding the output from the awk script, since this question is related to return codes specifically):

```
$ sudo -n zgrep -h AuthenticationAllowed /var/log/accountpolicy.log* 2>/dev/null | awk -v username="${USER}" -f ./parse-accountpoliocy.awk &>/dev/null
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0 0
```

You can see that `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` shows that both `sudo` and `awk` were successful, which is expected, as I know I have sudo access, and the awk variable `username` was set and has log entries.

#### Test #2 (working properly)

Now if we change the awk variable `username` to an account that *does not exist*, then the awk script should exit with a return code of `3`:

```
$ sudo -n zgrep -h AuthenticationAllowed /var/log/accountpolicy.log* 2>/dev/null | awk -v username="fakeuser" -f ./parse-accountpoliocy.awk &>/dev/null
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0 3
```

Perfect!

#### Test #3 (Problem..)

If I execute the command above, but neglect to define the `username` awk variable, then the awk script *should* exit with a return code of 2

```
$ sudo -n zgrep -h AuthenticationAllowed /var/log/accountpolicy.log* 2>/dev/null | awk -f ./parse-accountpoliocy.awk &>/dev/null
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
141 2
```

As you can see, the awk script *does* return `2`, but now for some reason, the `sudo`/`zgrep` returns `141`, despite the fact that that part of the command wasn't altered at all... and this is the problem I’m running into.

I even tried to execute the command without hiding the output (of either *STDOUT* or *STDERR*), and the result was the same, but no error was displayed:

```
$ sudo -n zgrep -h AuthenticationAllowed /var/log/accountpolicy.log*  | awk -f ./parse-accountpoliocy.awk
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
141 2
```

### Question

How can the exit code of the `awk` script change the exit code for the `sudo`/`zgrep` command stored within `${PIPESTATUS[@]}`?

---

#### Environmental Information

- OSx Version: 10.11.6 (El Capitan)
- Bash Version: 4.4.12
- AWK Version: GNU Awk 4.1.4

Comment: As an aside, because you already have your SIGPIPE answer, you don't need your `rows` variable as `awk` already has the `NR` variable bultin which counts the records (lines in this case).

Answer (score 6):

```
$ echo $((141-128))
13
$ kill -l | grep 13
13   PIPE Broken pipe                   29   INFO Information request
$
```

So that 141 is how the shell kluges the 16-bit exit status word (see `wait(2)`) containing a `PIPE` signal into a single number; this does not happen for the `exit 3` case as that happens *after* the data being piped has been done processed by `awk` (and `zgrep` has nothing more to write to `awk` via the pipe). The `exit 2` instead happens very early while `zgrep` still has data it wants to pipe to `awk`, so `zgrep` gets whacked with a `PIPE` when it tries to write to the `awk` that has gone away.